# Question preview in list

Tags: feature-request

I think it would be a great feature to be able to preview a question while you're scrolling through the list. Many times I find that I don't know by the title what exactly is the question about, whether it is relevant to me or I know the answer to the question. I then have to open the question and either go back and forth in the same tab or open new tabs while keeping the list open at the same time.

A small button that would load only the original question and show it slide down from the list entry would greatly help in this use case. Clicking on the button again would hide it, so that I can move on scrolling through the list.

Answer (score 2):

There is already a preview for the listed questions: Hover the mouse over the question title, and for [run javascript every 24 hours](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/74979/run-javascript-every-24-hours) you get the following tooltip.

> [image: screenshot]

It doesn't show any Markdown, and the preview is limited to X characters, but you can get an idea of what a question is asking without seeing the question.

On https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions, an excerpt of the questions is always shown.

> [image: screenshot]

That is true also for the search pages.

> [image: screenshot]

See also the pages listing all the questions using a tag.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Not exactly what I would prefer but it gives a quick idea. It works only in the homepage list though so it's of very limited usage. It doesn't show on search results or other lists.

Comment: You always get an excerpt of the questions, even on search pages.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, different UI confused me but it's there as you say

Answer (score 0):

When you browser from the [Questions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions) menu line instead of the homepage, you get the first two or three lines from the question w/o an markdown applied.  Personally, this is how I always read the site.

Comment: For me it works the other way around, from the Questions or other menu link I don't get a preview tooltip but I do in the homepage.